Embla Carousel Vue3 scrollNext Event
I'm hoping to get Embla Carousel setup in my Vue project, but I can't get the scrollNext function to work.
Here's where I am:
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import emblaCarouselVue from 'embla-carousel-vue'
import Autoplay from 'embla-carousel-autoplay'

const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = emblaCarouselVue({ loop: true }, [Autoplay()])

function prevSlide () {
  emblaApi.value.scrollPrev()
}

function nextSlide () {
  emblaApi.value.scrollNext()
} 
</script>

<template>
  <div class="embla" ref="emblaRef">
    <div class="embla__viewport">
      <div class="embla__container">
        <div class="embla__slide">
          <div class="embla__parallax">
            <div class="embla__parallax__layer">
              <img
                class="embla__slide__img embla__parallax__img"
                src="https://picsum.photos/1000/350?v=1"
                alt="Your alt text"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
...
    <button @click="prevSlide">Prev</button>
    <button @click="nextSlide">Next</button>


You can view the project using this codesandbox. The ideal solution would allow me to leverage the parallax effect as seen in the embla docs.

Not sure about that specific package but as a side comment, you could do that in vanilla CSS nowadays with very minimal JS.

Embla expects the first child element of the root to hold the slides. Since you added div.embla__viewport between the root and the container, you have to tell Embla about it via the container option:
const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = emblaCarouselVue({
  loop: true,
  container: '.embla__container', // <----- use custom container
}, [Autoplay()]);

I think you could also just move the template ref, Embla does not seem to use the classes internally.

The parallax effect is not a builtin, you have to use the code and styles from the example (see css/embla.css and js/EmblaCarouselTweenParallax.js in their sandbox).

Here is the updated stackblitz with these changes:

added the container option as described above
removed css in Carousel.vue
added file embla.css (copied from example sandbox)
added file composables/emblaParallax.js (copied from example sandbox)

wrapped init function so parallax is cleaned up on unmount


called useEmblaParallax() in Carousel.vue

Let me know, does that work for you?

Great answer, very comprehensive. Thx so much, I learned some things from this !

That's great! I'm happy.
